# How to print a string with its \n characters included?

Tags: c, printf, line-breaks

Let's say we have `char* str = "Hello world!\n"`. Obviously when you print this you will see `Hello world!`, but I want to make it so it will print `Hello world!\n`. Is there any way to print a string with its line break characters included?

Edit: I want to print `Hello world!\n` without changing the string itself. Obviously I could just do `char* str = "Hello world \\n"`.

Also, the reason I'm asking this question is because I'm using fopen to open a txt file with a ton of line breaks. After making the file into a string, I want to split the string by each of its line breaks so I can modify each line individually.

Comment: nitpick: You don't mean "included", but rather 'replaced with something visible', perhaps 'escaped'. They _always_ get "included", but just in the literal form that you don't want here.

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: There's... more than one question here... It's a bit confusing. To clarify, your question is, given a string from a text file, print the text with the newlines escaped?

Comment: You could always write your own `Myprintf(char *)` function, checking for the value of each char ...

Comment: Regarding your reason for asking the question, you can just split the string by each of the `'\n'` (newline) characters directly without replacing newlines with escape sequences.

Comment: Ian is right; this seems like an X/Y question, because C has no problem finding/splitting at newlines; they're just another character as far as it's concerned.

Comment: @underscore_d Yup my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a typical case of an XY Problem: you ask about a particular solution without really focusing on the original problem first.

> After making the file into a string

Why do you think you need to read the entire file in at once? That's not normally necessary.

> I want to split the string by each of its line breaks so I can modify each line individually.

You don't need to *print* the string to do that (you wanted "to make it so it will print `Hello World!\n`). You don't need to modify the string. You just need to *read it in line by line*! That's what [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is for:

```
void printFile(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    if (file) {
        char linebuf[1024];
        int lineno = 1;
        while (fgets(linebuf, sizeof(linebuf), file)) {
            // here, linebuf contains each line            
            char *end = linebuf + strlen(linebuf) - 1;
            if (*end == '\n')
                *end = '\0'; // remove the '\n'
            printf("%5d:%s\\n\n", lineno ++, linebuf);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

> I want to make it so it will print `Hello world!\n`

If you really wanted to do it, you'd have to translate the ASCII LF (that's what `\n` represents) to `\n` on output, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fprintWithEscapes(FILE *file, const char *str)
{
    const char *cr;
    while ((cr = strchr(str, '\n'))) {
        fprintf(file, "%.*s\\n", (int)(cr - str), str);
        str = cr + 1;
    }
    if (*str) fprintf(file, "%s", str);
}

int main() { 
    fprintWithEscapes(stdout, "Hello, world!\nA lot is going on.\n");
    fprintWithEscapes(stdout, "\nAnd a bit more...");
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");    
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!\nA lot is going on.\n\nAnd a bit more...
```

Comment: Sorry! It was actually my bad for making the question a little unrelated to what was really looking for. Thanks a ton! I thought that to get each line of a file, I would have to get the whole file as a string and split it by line breaks, guess not. Thankssss!

Comment: You really want to read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). I do mean actually read the whole thing. Once you do, you'll know all the I/O functionality provided in standard C language.